# custom notification with buttons, notification click causing button action

Tags: java, android, notifications

Im building an alarm app for Android ive created a custom notification with two buttons. Since ive added the buttons if i now click on the notification it seems to trigger the buttons action rather than the notification intent.
Also the second button in layout seems to also trigger the first button so basically any click on the notification or second button seems to register as a click on the first button.

Custom notification xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/notiflay"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="#000000">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
    android:text="Alarm"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dismiss"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button1"
        android:id="@+id/dismissnot"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Snooze"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:id="@+id/snoozenot"/>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Notification create code

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, 
lockscreenactivity.class);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("alarmno", alarmno);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("snooze", false);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("dismiss", false);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, alarmno, alarmIntent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent snoozeintnet = new Intent(this, 
lockscreenactivity.class);
    snoozeintnet.putExtra("alarmno", alarmno);
    snoozeintnet.putExtra("snooze", true);
    snoozeintnet.putExtra("dismiss", false);
    PendingIntent pendingsnooze = 
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, alarmno, snoozeintnet, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent dismissintent = new Intent(this, lockscreenactivity.class);
    dismissintent.putExtra("alarmno", alarmno);
    dismissintent.putExtra("dismiss", true);
    dismissintent.putExtra("snooze", false);
    PendingIntent pendingdismiss = 
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, alarmno, dismissintent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);



    int icon = R.drawable.notification;

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =  (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Alarm");
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(icon)
        .setContent(contentView)
        .setContentTitle("Alarm")
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
        ;


contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.dismissnot, 
                                        pendingdismiss);

  contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.snoozenot, 
                                        pendingsnooze);
    contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notiflay, 
                                        pendingIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(alarmno, notificationBuilder.build());
```